# Passing combination of python data structure and tf tensors as tf.while_loop variables

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, data-structures, while-loop

I need to use `tf.while_loop` for my project. Is it possible to pass a list of both python dictionary and tensorflow tensors as a list of variables for body and cond functions?

```
 a = {'state': 1 , 'path': 2}
 b = tf.get_variable(name = 'my_variable' , shape=[batch_size, None])
 state = {
    'x' : a ,
    'y' : b } 
shape = { 
    'y' : tf.TensorShape([batch_size, None])
   }
 tf.while_loop(
        cond, body, loop_vars=[state],
        shape_invariants=[shape], parallel_iterations=1, back_prop=False)
```

Comment: Please describe the problem with some details.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Please check the update. I have added a pseudo sample.